# Statistical Significance with Multivariate Logistic Regression and Feature Selection

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, p-value, feature-selection

**Background:**

Given a dataset with output `y` (Bernoulli distribution) and features `x_0, x_1, x_2, ..., x_n` I want to test which variables are statistically significant to the predictor `y`.  From what I remember from my stats classes, I can run these through a logistic regression model (`glm` in R) and get p-values for their statistical significance.

Now I understand that given many variables in a model, I should apply a correct such as the Bonferroni correction, etc. to prevent over optimism in my results.  This it not my question, as it seems straightforward.

**Question:**

My question is rather, if I try all subsets of my features `x_0, x_1, x_2, ..., x_n` in different combinations, will I need to apply any corrections to account for that?  I see that the p-values vary slightly as I add or drop variables from my feature list, and I don't want to accidentally end up p-hacking.

Similarly, does selecting a model using AIC/BIC and then putting those variables into the model for hypothesis testing affect the validity of my results?

Am I approaching this wrong? Should I be defining these hypothesis beforehand and then testing them?  Is it bad faith to throw it in a model and see what is significant?  I come from a machine learning background, where I feel like it is commonplace to throw all the data in and see what comes out.